# Can individual US states exchange territory without the approval of the US Congress?

Tags: united-states, constitution, federalism

The Admission Clause of the US Constitution reads as follows:

> New States may be admitted by the Congress into this Union; but no new States shall be formed or erected within the Jurisdiction of any other State; nor any State be formed by the Junction of two or more States, or parts of States, without the Consent of the Legislatures of the States concerned as well as of the Congress.

My question is, while it is clear that it requires the consent of Congress to form a **new** state between the territory of pre-existing states, what about an exchange of territory between 2 already existing states?

Could Oregon give Malheur County to California without the consent of Congress? Would this be the formation of a new state, that just happens to be composed of mostly California? Or, what I think seems more logical, merely the extension of a pre-existing State, and if so would the legality of such an event be determined solely by the constitutions of Oregon and California?

To be more succinct: can individual US States exchange territory between themselves without the consent of the Congress?